# javascript add/remove class from div id?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following div:

```
<div id="locker"></div>
```

My Div Id uses the below css styling:

```
#locker{
          width:20px;
height:20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:15px 15px;
background-position:5px center;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#fff;
padding:3px;
position:relative;
text-align: center;
margin:auto;
 filter: invert(75%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(75%);
    background-image: url('../images/padlock.png');


      }
```

I also have a class styling:

```
                  .locker2{ 
background-image: url('../images/key.png');
      }
```

when a user clicks on another div of mine I am running the below javascript and I want the background image of my Div 'locker' to change from the background image in `#locker` to the one in `.locker2`

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
<script>
    $('#edit').click(function(){
    $('input').prop('disabled', false);
    $('input').css("background", "transparent");
    $('#locker').removeClass('#locker').addClass("locker2");
    $('#submit').css("display", "block");
});
</script>
```

However the background image is not changing. Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Among other problems, `class` and `id` are two very different things; an `id` uniquely identifies one specific element, whereas a `class` identifies a multiple elements in a similar 'role.'

Comment: An ID is ***NOT*** a class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`locker` is the id of the element not a class, so for styling purposes it is easier to change your structure to a class like

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
  $('input').prop('disabled', false);
  $('input').css("background", "transparent");
  $('#locker').removeClass('locker').addClass("locker2");
  $('#submit').css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
#locker {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-position: 5px center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  filter: invert(75%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(75%);
}
.locker {
  background-image: url('//placehold.it/32X32/ff0000');
}
.locker2 {
  background-image: url('//placehold.it/32X32/ff00ff');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="edit">Edit</button>
<div id="locker" class="locker"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your code this worked great, There is a problem however, when the javascript changes the class it only changes it for the one instance o my <div id="locker" class="locker"></div> but I have 10 of them and want all 10 to change with each other